# AWK: Preserving the format when printing "print $0"

Tags: linux, awk, formatting, text-files

I am trying to use AWK for manipulating two files. Well I am actually interpolating between the two. Since I am not that much familiar how to process two files simultaneously with AWK I first do a paste

```
paste file_1 file_2 > mixed_file
```

each of those files contains lines of the following type

```
   2.02646E+12  ERR   7.39921E+09 EG =   67
   1.82357E+12  ERR   7.01570E+09 EG =   68
   8.65566E+11  ERR   4.35764E+09 EG =   69
```

The newly created file 'mixed_file' looks like this

```
 2.02646E+12  ERR   7.39921E+09 EG =   67        2.02646E+12  ERR   7.39921E+09 EG =   67
 1.82357E+12  ERR   7.01570E+09 EG =   68        1.82357E+12  ERR   7.01570E+09 EG =   68
 8.65566E+11  ERR   4.35764E+09 EG =   69        8.65566E+11  ERR   4.35764E+09 EG =   69
```

And here is my problem: when I try doing something like

```
awk  ' / EG = / {$1=0.5*($1+$7)}  {print $0} ' mixed_file
```

I get my formatting totally wrong

```
2026460000000 ERR 7.39921E+09 EG = 67 2.02646E+12 ERR 7.39921E+09 EG = 67
1823570000000 ERR 7.01570E+09 EG = 68 1.82357E+12 ERR 7.01570E+09 EG = 68
865566000000 ERR 4.35764E+09 EG = 69 8.65566E+11 ERR 4.35764E+09 EG = 69
```

I presume that the change in $1 is most probably due to mixing floats with characters. It is in principle possible to explicitly define the format and avoid this problem by using "printf", but I guess that more elegant solution exists.

AWK experts I would appreciate your help,

Thank you

Alex

Comment: you can put your calc'd value at the end of your line using `awk '/ EG = / {$(NF+1)=0.5*($1+$7)}  {print $0}' file` but per Etan's reply, it won't return the tab char to the output. At least (for your sample) the data looks neat after putting calced value to the end. You could pass that thru a printf statment to reinsert the tab. Good luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reassigning back to $0 is what you're after:

```
awk  '/ EG = / {$0 = sprintf(" %7.5E%s", 0.5*($1+$7), substr($0,13))} 1' mixed_file
```

Comment: Mr. Jackman Sir, thank you for your reply. This is indeed what I was looking for. There is one trailing integer I guess. I deleted it, so that your one-liner looks like this : `awk  '/ EG = / {$0 = sprintf("  %7.5E%s", 0.5*($1+$7), substr($0,12))} {print $0}' wrem.inp > kk`. To fully understand the above expression, I would like to ask one question: Is there some method to automatically fix the regex expression  `%7.5E%s`. Actually, I can simply use `%13.5E%s`, but for the sake of clarity I decided to ask this question.

Comment: The trailing integer is a short-hand notation for `{print $0}`. `%7.5E%s` is not a regular expression, is it the format string for the [`sprintf` function](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html#index-sprintf_0028_0029-function-1), and you can modify it to your heart's content.

Answer (score 3):

When you assign to a field awk re-formats the line.

It does that using the value of `OFS` (by default a space).

Your input had multiply spaced columns. awk doesn't recreate that.

You can pipe to `column -t` to recreate that sort of output if you want.

You can also set `OFS` to a tab (`\t`) if that gets you the output you want.

I don't know of a way to get awk itself to preserve input formatting though (though I think that the `RT` variable in newer versions of gawk might allow that to be done manually).

Comment: I think that I would have to live with `awk  ' / EG = / {$1=0.5*($1+$8); printf("%13.5E%5s%14.5E%3s %s  %3d%13.5E\n",$1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7)}  !/ EG = / {print $0}'`